# Easiest way to pull all metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

I want to pull metadata from a sandbox for the purpose of finding where in code a standard field is being referenced. My plan is to pull the meta-data and then search for references to the field.

Currently using sfdx I am able to pull apexclass using command

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapipkg -u <username> -k ./package.xml
```

My package.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>sotestcontroller</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

This returns the class in question, but I don't want to have to manually add in all the classes to get the data. I tried using this - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator visual studio code plugin but it just seemed to hang for ages and didn't generate anything.

What is the easiest way to get the metadata?

Comment: You can give wild character for member attribute and retrieve all the classes right. Are you saying it's not working?

Comment: I did not know that.

Comment: Oh, okie. Just give a wild character and you should be able to retrieve all classes at once. Wild character do not work for all the types of metadata but i know that it surely works for ApecClass. Good luck

Comment: You can also query for such dependencies using a Dependency API query.  I can explain more if you're interested

Comment: yes please! That'd be nice

Comment: ApexcClass supports wild character(*) , just replace `sotestcontroller` with `*` in your package.xml .  other way you can try in developer console edit-->Search in files

Comment: @Raj if you want to put that as the answer I will accept

Comment: @eaeaoo sure, will do that tomorrow morning. Will write something nice with references, off to bed for now. Thanks 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the resource URL from Salesforce : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm

To fetch all the class, you just need to include the below lines in your package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<version>48.0</version>
```

This metadata type supports the wildcard character * (asterisk) in the package.xml manifest file.